# What's the best practice to filter out specific year in query in Netezza?

Tags: filter, netezza

I am a SQL Server guy and just started working on Netezza, one thing pops up to me is a daily query to find out the size of a table filtered out by year: 2016,2015, 2014, ...

What I am using now is something like below and it works for me, but I wonder if there is a better way to do it:

```
select count(1) 
from table 
where extract(year from datacolumn) = 2016
```

extract is a built-in function, applying a function on a table with size like 10 billion+ is not imaginable in SQL Server to my knowledge.

Thank you for your advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only problem i see with the query is the where clause which executes a function on the 'variable' side. That effectively disables zonemaps and thus forces netezza to scan all data pages, not only those with data from that year.

Instead write something like:

```
select count(1) 
from table 
where  datecolumn between '2016-01-01' and '2016-12-31'
```

A more generic alternative is to create a 'date dimension table' with one row per day in your tables (and a couple of years into the future)
This is an example for Postgres: https://medium.com/@duffn/creating-a-date-dimension-table-in-postgresql-af3f8e2941ac

This enables you to write code like this:

```
Select count(1) 
From table t join d_date d on t.datecolumn=d.date_actual
Where year_actual=2016
```

You may not have the generate_series() function on your system, but a 'select row_number()...' can do the same trick. A download is available here: https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/wikis/basic/anonymous/api/wiki/76c5f285-8577-4848-b1f3-167b8225e847/page/44d502dd-5a70-4db8-b8ee-6bbffcb32f00/attachment/6cb02340-a342-42e6-8953-aa01cbb10275/media/generate_series.tgz

A couple of further notices in 'date interval' where clauses:

Those columns are the most likely candidate for a zonemaps optimization. Add a 'organize on (datecolumn)' at the bottom of your table DDL and organize your table. That will cause netezza to move around records to pages with similar dates, and the query times will be better.

Furthermore you should ensure that the 'distribute on' clause for the table results in an **even** distribution across data slices of the table is big. The execution of the query will never be faster than the slowest dataslice.

I hope this helps

Comment: Thank you very much for your input, I will have to try out your proposal tomorrow in office to find out the difference and hopefully the performance can be improved, thank you.